# Why can't I use javascript variable inside of FancyBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, fancybox

```
// Post Div
<div id="post-1"><img src="art/image01.jpg" /></div>
<div id="post-2"><img src="art/image02.jpg" /></div>
<div id="post-3"><img src="art/image03.jpg" /></div>

// MYSQL Json Encode Generated Information
var allPosts = [{"type":"tumblr", "link":"www.blah.com"},
    {"type":"instagram", "link":"blah.com"},
    {"type":"tumblr", "link":"www.blah.com"}]

var postTotals = 3;

// Generates FancyBox Links for Clickable Post Div
function generateFancyBox(){
    for(i=1;i<=postTotals;i++){
        $("#post-"+i).click(function(){
            alert(allPosts[i].link); // This alerts "www.blah.com" just fine.
            $.fancybox({
            "type" : "iframe",
            "href" : allPosts[i].link // This Variable is always "Undefined".
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `href` : `allPosts[i].link` - always becomes `undefined`.

This code is a shorthand version of a larger project I'm working on. I have html DIVs that I need FancyBox to create clickable links.

I can not seem to get the `allPosts[i].link` to print the `URL`. However, right above it, when I `alert(allPosts[i].link);` it prints the URL just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cab you fiddle your code http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Wrap fancy box in an IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the $.fancybox call with an immediately executing function, which creates a additional closure.

```
(function () {
        alert(i);
        $.fancybox({
            "type": "iframe",
            "href": allPosts[i].link // This Variable is always "Undefined".
        });
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

1) In the click event handler, wrap the click handler assignment in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).

[JSFiddle it.](http://jsfiddle.net/0r2wm10o/1/)

```
function generateFancyBox(){
    for(i=1;i<=postTotals;i++){
        (function (ii) {
            $("#post-"+ii).click(function(){
                console.log(allPosts[ii-1].link);                
                //$.fancybox({ "type" : "iframe", "href" : allPosts[ii-1].link });
            });
        }(i))
    }
}
```

By the time the click handler (and fancybox) does it's job, `i` is not what it was when it was passed, as a reference, to fancybox. Passing `i` in as a parameter to the IIFE you're creating a new scope with a new variable `ii` that gets locked in to the current value of the `for` loop `i` when it was passed to the click handler.

2) There's also a problem with the loop and DIV indexes not sync'ing with the image/link array. So I changed:

`allPosts[ii]` to `allPosts[ii-1]`

Your loop and image DIVs start with *"1"* as in `for(i=1;` and `post-1` but your image/link array is zero-based, which means it starts with *"0"* as in `allPosts[0]`. So when grabbing the image/link element, decrement counter by one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried using IIFE but I started to run into more errors. So, in order to avoid the problem all together, I'm now using PHP to generate fancyBox instead of Javascript. It's alot easier, I still can't figure out why it wouldn't work with Javascript. I think maybe there's just too many other things going on in my code - and perhaps it's just conflicting with fancybox.

Comment: I took a closer look and set up JSFiddle. That seems to work with the fixes mentioned in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you are creating *closures* inside a `loop`. See **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)**  for further information.

What you have to do is to create the *closure* **outside** of the `loop` and call it as the *handler* (or *callback*) of your `click` *event*, passing `i` as *argument*, so

the closure :

```
function launchFancybox(i) {
    return function () {
        $.fancybox({
            type: "iframe",
            href: allPosts[i].link
        });
    }
}
```

Then *bind* the `click` events to each `div` inside your `generateFancyBox()` *function* like :

```
function generateFancyBox() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allPosts.length; i++) {        
        $("#post-"+(i+1)).click( launchFancybox(i) );
    }
}
```

**NOTES** :

- we need to initialize `i` declaring it with `var` (in `strict` mode, it will return an `undeclared variable` error if you don't)
- notice that `i` should always start with `0`, otherwise you will never have access to the first element of the `allPosts` *array*. You need to use `(i+1)` to refer to each div's ID though.
- you don't actually need `var postTotals = 3;` since you can always refer to the `length` of your `allPosts` array

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9r905osk/)**